# View all documents in ng2-pdf-viewer

Tags: html, angular, pdf, pdf-viewer, ng2-pdfjs-viewer

In npm ng2-pdf-viewer is it possible that we can view images, excel, and other documents. I have base64 string of all documents but I want to view not only pdf but all documents. Is it possible? If so, can anyone help me?

Comment: you mean you have a base64 string and want to show when you open a pdf file you want to show that base64 string

Comment: @errorau I have multiple base64 strings which contains .pdf,.png,.xls files. I am looping the base64 string in html with <pdf-viewer>, but I can see only the pdf not .png and .xls files.

Answer (score 1):

As the [repo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-pdf-viewer) details it, `ng2-pdf-viewer` is just for PDF files. If you need to display Excel documents, photos, and so on, you should use a different component.

You can make a function that picks which component to use depending on what file type you have, but you cannot display them all in `ng2-pdf-viewer`.

[ViewerJS](https://viewerjs.org/) is an example of a Framework that supports both PDF and office documents (Open Document Format).